# change a column from nvarchar like YYYYMM to date type getting last day of month

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have a table called TABLE1 with a column called COL1 which values are nvarchar like this 202001. (YYYYMM)

I want to change the format of COL1 from nvarchar to date type (YYYY-MM-DD) getting also the last day of month.

From a nvarchar like 202001 then I want as ouput 2020-01-31 in date type with day = 31 because is last day of january.

I already tried with:

alter table TABLE1
alter column COL1  Date;

But got following error:
"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: tag your sql engine.

Comment: You will not be able to do it in one swipe. Create new column. Populate it. Delete old. Rename new.

Comment: In case my nvarchar column looks like 2020-01-31, how can i convert it to date?

Comment: Hover your mouse over the SQL tag you added, and read the description of that tag. It strongly suggests that you also add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, because syntax and functionality differs between them. By not adding that tag, you've made it take longer for you to get an answer, because people are waiting for you to add it so that they don't waste their time writing an answer only to find out it won't work on your DBMS. Please [edit] your post and add that DBMS tag.